# Why does values enclosed in multi line comment work in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically I have a print statement with a value enclosed in a multi line comment block. I am expecting it to be an error but I found out that it actually prints the text enclosed. I am curious as to why it does that.

```
print '''Test String'''
```

Comment: That's not a comment. It is a string. Python has no multi-line comment blocks.

Comment: I am new to python. I have thought they are multi line comments. Anyway I've learned that it's not today.

Comment: @AjitPeter I'm sure MartjinPieters didn't say that in any disdaining way, but simply wanted to give you information. Multilinestrings are a bit tricky and hard to google for if you don't know them already. Every python user had to learn them some day. Keep coding and stay curious!

Comment: I'm surprised at the down votes. Considering python's special-casing of some strings as doc strings, it was a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has no multi-line comment syntax. You got confused with one of the Python [string literal forms](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) instead.

`'''....'''` creates a *string*, just like `'...'` does. There is a `"""...."""` form as well. The difference is that newlines are permitted in the triple-quoted without requiring escaping:

```
multi_line_string = '''This is the first line.
But multiple lines are included.
And each newline is included in the value.
'''
```

You probably thought of these as comments because Python developers prefer this form when creating the *documentation string*. Python gives special meaning to a string literal used as the first statement in a module, class or function, storing the contents in the object `__doc__` attribute.

You don't *have* to use triple-quoted strings for that, single quotes work too:

```
>>> def foo():
...     'The foo function'
...     return 'bar'
... 
>>> foo.__doc__
'The foo function'
```

The Python style guide recommends you use triple-quoting, always, using double quotes, like this:

```
def recommended():
    """This is a documentation string.

    It follows the style guide by using triple quotes.

    """
```

See the [PEP 257: *Docstring Conventions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for more information.

Comment: Sometimes multiline strings are "abused" as comments, which is probably why the author got confused.

Comment: @syntonym: perhaps, but most Python beginners first see them used as docstrings, which may look like comments to the uninitiated.

Answer (score -1):

Lines enclosed with three quotes are not comments, they are strings. However, [python](/questions/tagged/python) can take them as a comment, the same way this is also a comment

```
"foo"
#bar
"""foobar"""
```

Comment: They are still (supposed) to be *executed*. The string is still part of the bytecode. It is perhaps *usable* as a comment, but it is not the same thing. CPython can optimise single string literals that are not assigned away but that's not a language feature. They are still parsed as tokens (while comments are not).

Comment: Python does not take them as comments, but strings just do nothing if stated. In the interactive interpreter it would output the string, just like stating a variable would do. As far as I know if compiled to bytecode it will be optimized away, but it's still not the same thing as a comment.

Comment: A docstring is not a comment. A comment is only single-line in Python with a #. Comments, by definition, have *no effect on the compiled source*. However, docstrings *do have an effect on the compiled source*.

Comment: @Shashank A docstring is a string directly following a definition (of class, function, module). You can use single line string `"bar"` or multilinestrings for it, but you can also do other things with multiline strings, e.g. `a = """a multiline string"""`